# Getting the target or source of an edge in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

Given a graph fg, my example:

```
library("igraph")

fg <- feature.graph <- graph.empty()

fg <- fg + vertices("root", "ho", "ha", value=c(1,2,3)) +
  edges(c("root", "ho", "root", "ha"), label=c("en", "an"), prob=c(0.2,0.8))
```

I extract an edge of interest:

```
> edge.of.interest <- E(fg)[from("root")][[1]]
> edge.of.interest
Edge sequence:
    e             
e [1] root -> ho
```

To now get the source or the target of this edge I can do:

```
> get.edge(fg, edge.of.interest)
[1] 1 2
> get.edge(fg, edge.of.interest)[1]
[1] 1
> get.edge(fg, edge.of.interest)[2]
[1] 2
```

I would have expected a function source and target with this effect:

```
> target(edge.of.interest)
2
```

I have been unable to find this or equivalent functions.  Is the method through get.edge the best there is?

Comment: You are trying to get vertices from edges, right? But wouldn't it be easier to try to directly have vertices from your graph? With function `neighbors` for example?

Comment: I am going to randomly walk over the graph; when at a given vertex, any of the edges leading away from it are taken with probability given by attribute prob of the edge.  At least intuitively this makes more sense through selecting an edge.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I know it is an old question but it looks like I have an answer from the top of my head. Do you mean `tail_of` and `head_of` ?

```
> head_of(fg, edge.of.interest)$value
[1] 1

> tail_of(fg, edge.of.interest)$value
[1] 2
```

Also, `ends` function may be useful here if both ends are needed at the same time.

Comment: Do you know if there is any equivalent function of ends for igraph in python?

Comment: what is equivalent python igraph function ??